# MediaPlayer stops playing the sounds - Android

Tags: android, audio, media, playback

Here is a simple piano app and it works but there is a problem. After about 20 clicks (sometimes it is exactly 28 clicks) even I click the buttons it doesn't play any sound. The app doesnt crash or doesn't warn me about anything. It is just nothing . There is no sound. Do you have any idea?

```
package com.example.playaudio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private MediaPlayer mp2;
        private MediaPlayer mp3;
        private MediaPlayer mp4;
        private MediaPlayer mp5;
        private MediaPlayer mp6;
        private MediaPlayer mp7;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
            Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
            Button button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_3);
            Button button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_4);
            Button button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_5);
            Button button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_6);
            Button button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_7);

            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
            button3.setOnClickListener(this);
            button4.setOnClickListener(this);
            button5.setOnClickListener(this);
            button6.setOnClickListener(this);
            button7.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int resId;
            int resId2;
            int resId3;
            int resId4;
            int resId5;
            int resId6;
            int resId7;


            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_1:
                resId = R.raw.a;
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);

                mp.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button_2:
                resId2 = R.raw.b;
                mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId2);
                mp2.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button_3:
                resId3 = R.raw.c;
                mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId3);
                mp3.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button_4:
                resId4 = R.raw.d;
                mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId4);
                mp4.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button_5:
                resId5 = R.raw.e;
                mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId5);
                mp5.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button_6:
                resId6 = R.raw.f;
                mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId6);
                mp6.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button_7:
                resId7 = R.raw.p;
                mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId7);
                mp7.start();
                break;

            }


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }



    }
```

Comment: The problem solved. Add release methods before mp = MediaPlayer ...


 

                       if(mp!=null)
   {
                    mp.release();
                    }
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
   mp.start();

Comment: I have the same kind of issue in my app. I have tried out releasing player before creating. Still, issue exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you're creating a new MediaPlayer instance to play each sound. You should either reuse them or clean them up.

From the [documentation of the MediaPlayer.create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) method:

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On
>   success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be
>   called again.
>
> **When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources.** If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.

Comment: Yes i realised and tried that and it worked. I was going to edit my question about the true version and since your answer is right i accepted it. Thank you for your concern :)

Comment: but how can I call `release` only when the sound is done playing?  surely I cant call `.start()` and then immediately `.release()` ?

Comment: @Zapnologica You can set a [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) to be notified when playback completes.

Answer (score 4):

simple way is to add onComplationListener

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer p1) {
        p1.release();
    }
});
```