# Buttons don't work after spam on a sound board I made?

Tags: java, android, apk

Okay so whats happening is I made an android app, and when I compile this code it builds fine and works pretty well, but when you spam the sounds or press enough of them the buttons stop playing sounds. sometimes all the buttons or just a few. Either way i really need to fix it, and there probably is something stupid I'm missing. So please help, thanks. I had to cut out some of the code at the bottom, so if it look like its missing something, that because I had to cut it out. Also, all the sounds do work. It just glitches when you spam, or press alot of buttons.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final MediaPlayer potatomp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.apotatoflewaroundmyroom);

    Button potato = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.potato);
    potato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(potatomp.isPlaying()) {
                potatomp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                potatomp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer Timemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aintnobodygottimefordat);

    Button Time = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Time);
    Time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(Timemp.isPlaying()) {
                Timemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                Timemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer Ballsmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ballsareperfect);




            else {
                getthecameramp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer graphmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.graph);

    Button graph = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    graph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(graphmp.isPlaying()) {
                graphmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                graphmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer hagaymp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hagay);

    Button hagay = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.hagay);
    hagay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(hagaymp.isPlaying()) {
                hagaymp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                hagaymp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer hatersouttheremp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hatersoutthere);

    Button hatersoutthere = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.hatersoutthere);
    hatersoutthere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(hatersouttheremp.isPlaying()) {
                hatersouttheremp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                hatersouttheremp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer im11mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.im11);

    Button im11 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.im11);
    im11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(im11mp.isPlaying()) {
                im11mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                im11mp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer imaginationmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.imagination);

    Button imagination = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.imagination);
    imagination.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(imaginationmp.isPlaying()) {
                imaginationmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                imaginationmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer iridocyclitismp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.iridocyclitis);

    Button iridocyclitis = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.iridocyclitis);
    iridocyclitis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(iridocyclitismp.isPlaying()) {
                iridocyclitismp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                iridocyclitismp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer isyoublindmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.isyoublind);

    Button isyoublind = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.isyoublind);
    isyoublind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isyoublindmp.isPlaying()) {
                isyoublindmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                isyoublindmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer patriciamp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.patricia);

    final Button patricia = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.patricia);
    patricia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(patriciamp.isPlaying()) {
                patriciamp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                patriciamp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer raviolimp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ravioli);

    Button ravioli = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ravioli);
    ravioli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(raviolimp.isPlaying()) {
                raviolimp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                raviolimp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer justdoitmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.justdoit);

    Button justdoit = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.justdoit);
    justdoit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(justdoitmp.isPlaying()) {
                justdoitmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                justdoitmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer lebronjamesmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lebronjames);

    Button lebronjames = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.lebronjames);
    lebronjames.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(lebronjamesmp.isPlaying()) {
                lebronjamesmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                lebronjamesmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer michaelscottmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.michaelscott);

    Button michaelscott = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.michaelscott);
    michaelscott.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(michaelscottmp.isPlaying()) {
                michaelscottmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                michaelscottmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer mlgairhornmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mlgairhorn);

    Button mlgairhorn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.mlgairhorn);
    mlgairhorn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mlgairhornmp.isPlaying()) {
                mlgairhornmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                mlgairhornmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer mynameisjeffmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mynameisjeff);

    Button mynameisjeff = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.mynameisjeff);
    mynameisjeff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mynameisjeffmp.isPlaying()) {
                mynameisjeffmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                mynameisjeffmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer noimnotmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.noimnot);

    final Button noimnot = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.noimnot);
    noimnot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(noimnotmp.isPlaying()) {
                noimnotmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                noimnotmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer nonofmybusinessmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nonofmybusiness);

    Button nonofmybusiness = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.nonofmybusiness);
    nonofmybusiness.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(nonofmybusinessmp.isPlaying()) {
                nonofmybusinessmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                nonofmybusinessmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer nothingisimpossiblemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nothingisimpossible);

    Button nothingisimpossible = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.nothingisimpossible);
    nothingisimpossible.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(nothingisimpossiblemp.isPlaying()) {
                nothingisimpossiblemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                nothingisimpossiblemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer onequestionforyoump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.onequestionforyou);

    Button onequestionforyou = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.onequestionforyou);
    onequestionforyou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(onequestionforyoump.isPlaying()) {
                onequestionforyoump.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                onequestionforyoump.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer reallymp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.really);

    Button really = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.really);
    really.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(reallymp.isPlaying()) {
                reallymp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                reallymp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer retardalertmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.retardalert);

    Button retardalert = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.retardalert);
    retardalert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(retardalertmp.isPlaying()) {
                retardalertmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                retardalertmp.start();
            }
        }
    });


    final MediaPlayer shalissamp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shalissa);

    final Button shalissa = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.shalissa);
    shalissa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(shalissamp.isPlaying()) {
                shalissamp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                shalissamp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer sharknomp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sharkno);

    final Button sharkno = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.sharkno);
    sharkno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(sharknomp.isPlaying()) {
                sharknomp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                sharknomp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer surprisemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.surprise);

    final Button surprise = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.surprise);
    surprise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(surprisemp.isPlaying()) {
                surprisemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                surprisemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer thiskidisoncrackmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thiskidisoncrack);

    final Button thiskidisoncrack = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.thiskidisoncrack);
    thiskidisoncrack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(thiskidisoncrackmp.isPlaying()) {
                thiskidisoncrackmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                thiskidisoncrackmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer thomasthedankenginemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thomasthedankengine);

    final Button thomasthedankengine = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.thomasthedankengine);
    thomasthedankengine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(thomasthedankenginemp.isPlaying()) {
                thomasthedankenginemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                thomasthedankenginemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer rkoouttanowheremp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rkoouttanowhere);

    final Button rkoouttanowhere = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.rkoouttanowhere);
    rkoouttanowhere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(rkoouttanowheremp.isPlaying()) {
                rkoouttanowheremp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                rkoouttanowheremp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer turtlesmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.turtles);

    final Button turtles = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.turtles);
    turtles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(turtlesmp.isPlaying()) {
                turtlesmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                turtlesmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer twentyonemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.twentyone);

    final Button twentyone = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.twentyone);
    twentyone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(twentyonemp.isPlaying()) {
                twentyonemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                twentyonemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer whatarethosemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whatarethose);

    final Button whatarethose = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.whatarethose);
    whatarethose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(whatarethosemp.isPlaying()) {
                whatarethosemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                whatarethosemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer whatareyouwaitingformp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whatareyouwaitingfor);

    final Button whatareyouwaitingfor = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.whatareyouwaitingfor);
    whatareyouwaitingfor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(whatareyouwaitingformp.isPlaying()) {
                whatareyouwaitingformp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else {
                whatareyouwaitingformp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer whatsnineplustenmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whatsnineplusten);

    final Button whatsnineplusten = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.whatsnineplusten);
    whatsnineplusten.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (whatsnineplustenmp.isPlaying()) {
                whatsnineplustenmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                whatsnineplustenmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer youstupidmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.youstupid);

    final Button youstupid = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.youstupid);
    youstupid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (youstupidmp.isPlaying()) {
                youstupidmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                youstupidmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer whywouldyousaythatmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whywouldyousaythat);

    final Button whywouldyousaythat = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.whywouldyousaythat);
    whywouldyousaythat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (whywouldyousaythatmp.isPlaying()) {
                whywouldyousaythatmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                whywouldyousaythatmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer yourenotmydadmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourenotmydad);

    final Button yourenotmydad = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.yourenotmydad);
    yourenotmydad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (yourenotmydadmp.isPlaying()) {
                yourenotmydadmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                yourenotmydadmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer whyyoumadsinglemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whyyoumadsingle);

    final Button whyyoumadsingle = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.whyyoumadsingle);
    whyyoumadsingle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (whyyoumadsinglemp.isPlaying()) {
                whyyoumadsinglemp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                whyyoumadsinglemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer wheredyoufindthismp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wheredyoufindthis);

    final Button wheredyoufindthis = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.wheredyoufindthis);
    wheredyoufindthis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (wheredyoufindthismp.isPlaying()) {
                wheredyoufindthismp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                wheredyoufindthismp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer wheresthepizzamp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wheresthepizza);

    final Button wheresthepizza = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.wheresthepizza);
    wheresthepizza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (wheresthepizzamp.isPlaying()) {
                wheresthepizzamp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                wheresthepizzamp.start();
            }
        }
    });
    final MediaPlayer itsjohncenamp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.itsjohncena);

    final Button itsjohncena = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.itsjohncena);
    itsjohncena.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (itsjohncenamp.isPlaying()) {
                itsjohncenamp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                itsjohncenamp.start();
            }
        }
    });
    final MediaPlayer nosleepmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nosleep);

    final Button nosleep = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.nosleep);
    nosleep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (nosleepmp.isPlaying()) {
                nosleepmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                nosleepmp.start();
            }
        }
    });


    Button stop = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {

            }
            if(hatersouttheremp.isPlaying()){
                hatersouttheremp.pause();
                hatersouttheremp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(im11mp.isPlaying()){
                im11mp.pause();
                im11mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(imaginationmp.isPlaying()){
                imaginationmp.pause();
                imaginationmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(iridocyclitismp.isPlaying()){
                iridocyclitismp.pause();
                iridocyclitismp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(isyoublindmp.isPlaying()){
                isyoublindmp.pause();
                isyoublindmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(patriciamp.isPlaying()){
                patriciamp.pause();
                patriciamp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(raviolimp.isPlaying()){
                raviolimp.pause();
                raviolimp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(justdoitmp.isPlaying()){
                justdoitmp.pause();
                justdoitmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(lebronjamesmp.isPlaying()){
                lebronjamesmp.pause();
                lebronjamesmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(rkoouttanowheremp.isPlaying()){
                rkoouttanowheremp.pause();
                rkoouttanowheremp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(michaelscottmp.isPlaying()){
                michaelscottmp.pause();
                michaelscottmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(mlgairhornmp.isPlaying()){
                mlgairhornmp.pause();
                mlgairhornmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(mynameisjeffmp.isPlaying()){
                mynameisjeffmp.pause();
                mynameisjeffmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(noimnotmp.isPlaying()){
                noimnotmp.pause();
                noimnotmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(nonofmybusinessmp.isPlaying()){
                nonofmybusinessmp.pause();
                nonofmybusinessmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(nothingisimpossiblemp.isPlaying()){
                nothingisimpossiblemp.pause();
                nothingisimpossiblemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(onequestionforyoump.isPlaying()){
                onequestionforyoump.pause();
                onequestionforyoump.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(reallymp.isPlaying()){
                reallymp.pause();
                reallymp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(retardalertmp.isPlaying()){
                retardalertmp.pause();
                retardalertmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(shalissamp.isPlaying()){
                shalissamp.pause();
                shalissamp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(itsjohncenamp.isPlaying()){
                itsjohncenamp.pause();
                itsjohncenamp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(sharknomp.isPlaying()){
                sharknomp.pause();
                sharknomp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(surprisemp.isPlaying()){
                surprisemp.pause();
                surprisemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(whyyoumadsinglemp.isPlaying()){
                whyyoumadsinglemp.pause();//wrong place
                whyyoumadsinglemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(thiskidisoncrackmp.isPlaying()){
                thiskidisoncrackmp.pause();
                thiskidisoncrackmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(thomasthedankenginemp.isPlaying()){
                thomasthedankenginemp.pause();
                thomasthedankenginemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(turtlesmp.isPlaying()){
                turtlesmp.pause();
                turtlesmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(twentyonemp.isPlaying()){
                twentyonemp.pause();
                twentyonemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(whatarethosemp.isPlaying()){
                whatarethosemp.pause();
                whatarethosemp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(whatareyouwaitingformp.isPlaying()){
                whatareyouwaitingformp.pause();
                whatareyouwaitingformp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(whatsnineplustenmp.isPlaying()){
                whatsnineplustenmp.pause();
                whatsnineplustenmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(youstupidmp.isPlaying()){
                youstupidmp.pause();
                youstupidmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(whywouldyousaythatmp.isPlaying()){
                whywouldyousaythatmp.pause();
                whywouldyousaythatmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(yourenotmydadmp.isPlaying()){
                yourenotmydadmp.pause();
                yourenotmydadmp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(wheredyoufindthismp.isPlaying()){
                wheredyoufindthismp.pause();
                wheredyoufindthismp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if(wheresthepizzamp.isPlaying()){
                wheresthepizzamp.pause();
                wheresthepizzamp.seekTo(0);
            }





        }
    });


}}
```

Comment: Define **spam**. `spam` is either `spiced ham` or `undesired messages`.  I couldn't find other translations. So, I can't find a sense in `spam on a sound board` or `spam the sounds` or `glitches when you spam`

Comment: I mean hitting multiple buttons alot or at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:
[MediaPlayer stops playing the sounds - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665250/mediaplayer-stops-playing-the-sounds-android)
Maybe you should consider recycling a single MediaPlayer instead of using multiple instances.

If you continue to have problems, another option that works well when playing multiple sound files at the same time is SoundPool http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html