# Cant play sound more then 7 times in android

Tags: android, media

When i play sound files in android i am getting this error:

> 11-17 15:58:14.482 158-20904/? E/OMXNodeInstance:
>   setConfig(f3f:google.mp3.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR:
>   Undefined(0x80001001) 11-17 15:58:14.482 158-20904/? I/ACodec: codec
>   does not support config priority (err -2147483648) 11-17 15:58:14.483
>   158-20904/? I/MediaCodec: MediaCodec will operate in async mode 11-17
>   15:58:14.488 158-20902/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for
>   AudioTrack size=131176 11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/? D/MemoryDealer: 
>   AudioTrack (0xb731c9f0, size=1048576) 11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/?
>   D/MemoryDealer:     0: 0xb94bbdf8 | 0x00000000 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17
>   15:58:14.488 158-20902/? D/MemoryDealer:     1: 0xb94bbe28 |
>   0x00020080 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/?
>   D/MemoryDealer:     2: 0xb7bb4438 | 0x00040100 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17
>   15:58:14.488 158-20902/? D/MemoryDealer:     3: 0xb7be71f8 |
>   0x00060180 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/?
>   D/MemoryDealer:     4: 0xb94bbca8 | 0x00080200 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17
>   15:58:14.488 158-20902/? D/MemoryDealer:     5: 0xb7321998 |
>   0x000A0280 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/?
>   D/MemoryDealer:     6: 0xb73883d0 | 0x000C0300 | 0x00020080 | A  11-17
>   15:58:14.488 158-20902/? D/MemoryDealer:     7: 0xb9e4f420 |
>   0x000E0380 | 0x0001FC80 | F  11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/?
>   D/MemoryDealer:   size allocated: 918400 (896 KB) 11-17 15:58:14.488
>   158-20902/? E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no
>   control block? 11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/? E/AudioTrack:
>   AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12 11-17 15:58:14.488
>   158-20902/? E/AudioSink: Unable to create audio track 11-17
>   15:58:14.488 158-20902/? W/NuPlayerRenderer: openAudioSink: non
>   offloaded open failed status: -19 11-17 15:58:14.488 158-20902/?
>   W/NuPlayerRenderer: onDrainAudioQueue(): audio sink is not ready 11-17
>   15:58:14.489 158-20902/? W/NuPlayerRenderer: onDrainAudioQueue():
>   audio sink is not ready 11-17 15:58:14.489 158-20902/?
>   W/NuPlayerRenderer: onDrainAudioQueue(): audio sink is not ready 11-17
>   15:58:14.490 158-20902/? W/NuPlayerRenderer: onDrainAudioQueue():
>   audio sink is not ready

here is my code:

```
    public void playSound(int n) 
    {
       try {
                Log.e("n value is", "" + n);
                boolean mStartPlaying = true;
                if (mStartPlaying == true) {
                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://packagename/" + beeb.mp3);
                    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(soundListener);
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), uri);
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    mPlayer.setLooping(false);
                    mPlayer.start();

                } else {
                    //   stopPlaying();
                    //rePlay.setText("Replay");
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    mPlayer.release();
                    mPlayer = null;
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ERR", "prepare() failed");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you playing sound files, is it via code?

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://fsu.android.RotaryDialer/" + activity.SOUNDS_R[n]);
                mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(soundListener);
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), uri);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.setLooping(false);
                mPlayer.start();

Comment: It looks, like you have a memory issue: AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size

Comment: Yeah but i don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: By properly posting your code, edit your post.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen that issue caused by not adequately releasing the mediaplayer. It seems to be able to keep playing 6 more times without the proper release, but at 7 times it has to start releasing threads.

Before starting your media player, or using the create command, check if it's null, and if it's not null, clean it up. First stop it if it's playing, or looping. Once it's stopped, then release it, and then make it null. Once that's been done you should be able to safely use the create command, and start playing.

```
   if (mp != null){
        if (mp.isPlaying()||mp.isLooping()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }


    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound);   // note that R = res folder, raw = raw subfolder holding my audio files, and sound is the name of one of the audio files


    mp.start();
```

Comment: also see this somewhat related post, but after all the research I've done to come up with this I thought it was worth sharing what I was able to make work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665250/mediaplayer-stops-playing-the-sounds-android?rq=1

Comment: it still remain issue.